# Remote partitioning without shared datasource

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am writing a remote partitioning job and able to run the job fine with a shared datasource(MySql) but when I want to run the job where I don't want the shared database between master and remote slaves, remote slaves fails when it receives the message from the master with the following exception.

`Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.step.NoSuchStepException: No StepExecution could be located for this request: StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=1, stepExecutionId=2, stepName=remoteSlavePartition]`

How can I resolve this? Below are the beans I use for my job. Let me know if you need any more beans to get more clarity.

```
@Bean
@Profile("master")
public PartitionHandler partitionHandler(MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate, PollableChannel replyPollableChannel) throws Exception {
    MessageChannelPartitionHandler partitionHandler = new MessageChannelPartitionHandler();

    partitionHandler.setStepName("remoteSlavePartition");
    partitionHandler.setGridSize(5);
    partitionHandler.setMessagingOperations(messagingTemplate);
    partitionHandler.setPollInterval(5000l);
    partitionHandler.setReplyChannel(replyPollableChannel);

    partitionHandler.afterPropertiesSet();

    return partitionHandler;
}

@Bean
@Profile("slave")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundRequests", outputChannel = "outboundStaging")
public StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler() {
    StepExecutionRequestHandler stepExecutionRequestHandler =
            new StepExecutionRequestHandler();

    BeanFactoryStepLocator stepLocator = new BeanFactoryStepLocator();
    stepLocator.setBeanFactory(this.applicationContext);
    stepExecutionRequestHandler.setStepLocator(stepLocator);
    stepExecutionRequestHandler.setJobExplorer(this.jobExplorer);

    return stepExecutionRequestHandler;
}

@Bean
@Profile("master")
public IntegrationFlow amqpInboundForHandlingSlaveResponses(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, responseQueue()))
                            .aggregate()
                            .channel(replyPollableChannel())
                            .get();
}

@Bean
@Profile("slave")
public PollableChannel outboundStaging() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean
@Profile("slave")
public IntegrationFlow sendRepliesFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(outboundStaging())
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)
                    .defaultDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT)
                    .routingKey("partition.responses"))
            .get();
}

@Bean
@Profile("slave")
public QueueChannel inboundRequests() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}
```

Is there any way I can have the slave and master not use the same database and yet run the job in remote partitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shared datasource is a requirement for remote partitioning.  The reason for that is the metadata for the steps is maintained in the same repository.  Each of the worker steps is still a step of the same job and so needs to be reported as such.