# Spring Batch remote partitioning with Hazelcast

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, hazelcast

I'm trying to refactor my existing Spring Batch job with Spring Batch remote partitioning. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256947/remote-partitioning-without-shared-datasource) and on [other tutorials](https://arnoldgalovics.com/spring-batch-remote-partitioning-kafka/) the common way is to define an `IntegrationFlow` in order to handle the `QueueChannel` by the concrete Queue implementation (e.g. Kafka or in my case Hazelcast).

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow() {
    KafkaProducerMessageHandler messageHandler = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler(kafkaTemplate);
    messageHandler.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(Constants.TOPIC_NAME));
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(outboundRequests())
            .log()
            .handle(messageHandler)
            .get();
}
```

Now I got the problem that I cannot find any Hazelcast specific way to create some MessageHandler. In `spring-integration-hazelcast` there is only the `HazelcastCacheWritingMessageHandler`, but that seems to be cache specific.

Does somebody has any idea? Does anyone have reference literature to implement Spring Batch remote partitioning with Hazelcast? the only [thing I could](https://github.com/cegeka/batchers/blob/master/taxcalculator-blog/article5-parallel-processing-using-threads-and-hazelcast/README.md) find seems to be outdated.

Thanks, Rokko

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably the name of the `HazelcastCacheWritingMessageHandler` is not OK, but it really can put data into an `ITopic` or `IQueue`:

```
    else if (object instanceof ITopic) {
        ((ITopic) object).publish(objectToStore);
    }
    else if (object instanceof Collection) {
        if (objectToStore instanceof Collection) {
            ((Collection) object).addAll((Collection) objectToStore);
        }
        else {
            ((Collection) object).add(objectToStore);
        }
    }
```

We even mention that in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/6.1.0-M2/reference/html/hazelcast.html#hazelcast-outbound-channel-adapter